# How to update the cookie value using jQuery? I don't want to update the cookie expire time?

Tags: php, jquery

I have the cookie for delete Option. But when the user uses the undo feature, I want to update the cookie. The cookie is set to expire in 5 minutes when created.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. That's why two other users may have voted it down. Please explain more clearly.

Answer (score -1):

use the [jquery.cookie](http://www.stilbuero.de/2006/09/17/cookie-plugin-for-jquery/) plugin